# Why is LINQ query to DataTable not working?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, datatable

I have a DataTable, dt, that contains the following: [image]

As you can see, there are two sets of files here: baseline (columns 1-3) and target (columns 4-6). So in this case I have 4 baseline files, m4, m5, m1, and m3 (m1 in row 5 is copied from row 3) and one target file, m1. The problem is that the information for the baseline file m1.txt is duplicated, so I'm trying to remove it using the following LINQ statement:

```
var extraneousRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
    Where(
        row => row["BASELINE_FOLDER"] == baselineSubfolder
        && row["BASELINE_FILE"] == baselineFilename
        && row["BASELINE_CHECKSUM"] == baselineChecksum
        && row["STATUS"] == "remove"
    ).ToArray();

foreach (DataRow dr in extraneousRows)
    {
        dt.Rows.Remove(dr);
    }
```

This should remove the 3rd row from the DataTable but it doesn't. The code works fine if I omit the      `&& row["STATUS"] == "remove"` line, so I know it's functional. And the values for baselineSubfolder, baselineFilename, and baselineChecksum are correct, so that's not the problem.

But for some reason, when I include that line about the status column, it doesn't detect that that row is in the DataTable, even though it clearly is according to the DataSet Visualizer (photo above). So it's never entering the foreach loop and not removing the necessary files. Why???

I maybe should mention that the baseline file information (first 4 rows) are being retrieved from a database, whereas the target file fields are being generated according to user input. I don't see how it would matter where the information is coming from, though, since I'm querying the DataTable directly...

**UPDATE**

Ok, after following the suggestions of idipous and Jamie Keeling, I've determined that the problem had to do with the foreach loop, which was never being populated. Since this query should only ever return a single row, I eliminated the loop altogether. My revised code looks like this:

```
var extraneousRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
    Where(
        row => row["BASELINE_FOLDER"] == baselineSubfolder
        && row["BASELINE_FILE"] == baselineFilename
        && row["BASELINE_CHECKSUM"] == baselineChecksum
        && row["STATUS"] == "remove"
    ).SingleOrDefault();

dt.Rows.Remove(extraneousRows);
```

For whatever reason, extraneousRows remains null and that last line is generating a runtime error: `IndexOutOfRangeException: The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection`

Why isn't this working?

Comment: In the picture the status is remove not removed. Not sure if this is it though.

Comment: if i where you i would trace the value of the status row, it will show you what it expect as a value !

Comment: @idipous yeah that was a typo. Not the problem though. It's actually supposed to be null but I was wondering if it was a null-related syntax problem so I changed it to "remove"

Comment: check row["STATUS"].ToString() == ...

Comment: @idipous how do I check it though? The LINQ query executes as one statement so I'm not sure how to view an individual line when debugging

Comment: When debugging you can breakpoint to the query and inspect all components of the lambda.

Comment: @idipous ok gotcha, yeah it says remove for the four files... but it still doesn't enter the foreach loop

Comment: Have you checked to see whether 'extraneousRows' has any elements to iterate over?

Comment: @JamieKeeling hmm it says extraneousRows {System.Data.DataRow[0]} so I'm guessing that means it has zero?

Comment: @JamieKeeling actually I don't need the loop at all because it should only ever match a single row, but not sure how to modify the LINQ statement to exclude the foreach loop

Comment: Instead of toArray() use SingleOrDefault();

Comment: @idipous ok but then what would the remove statement look like?

Comment: The same. It still returns a Row. Just one. It's the same as running a query and using top 1 in the sql.

Comment: well I can't use dt.Rows.Remove(dr); on its own because dr is defined in the foreach line. Can't use the foreach loop anymore either because now it's giving this error: `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Data.DataRow' because 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'`

Comment: No no, you do not use foreach at all. you have only one datarow dt.Rows.Remove(extraneousRows);

Comment: @idipous I tried that too. It gives an `IndexOutOfRangeException: The given DataRow is not in the current DataRowCollection`. And when I debug, the value of extraneousRows is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually turns out that the problem was that I needed to cast the column values to strings. The solution was incredibly simple: just add a .ToString() after the column names and viola! The following code worked like a charm:

```
var extraneousRows = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().
    Where(
        row => row["BASELINE_FOLDER"].ToString() == baselineSubfolder
        && row["BASELINE_FILE"].ToString() == baselineFilename
        && row["BASELINE_CHECKSUM"].ToString() == baselineChecksum
        && row["STATUS"].ToString() == "remove"
    ).SingleOrDefault();

dt.Rows.Remove(extraneousRows);
```

I also found a non-LINQ way to do this, by iterating through all the rows of the DataTable. It's not the most efficient, but it works:

```
for (int z = 0; z < dt.Rows.Count; z++)
{
    if ((dt.Rows[z]["BASELINE_FOLDER"].ToString() == baselineSubfolder)
        && (dt.Rows[z]["BASELINE_FILE"].ToString() == baselineFilename)
        && (dt.Rows[z]["BASELINE_CHECKSUM"].ToString() == baselineChecksum)
        && (dt.Rows[z]["STATUS"].ToString() == "remove"))
    {
        dt.Rows[z].Delete();
    }
}
dt.AcceptChanges();
```